# How to give foreign key a name in RoR 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

***How can I give foreign key a name in RoR?***

I use following command to give foreign key:

```
rails generate scaffold Table2 id:integer Table1:references
```

This command `adds foreign key of Table1 in Table2` but with default name that is `Table1_id`. So how can I give custom name to it for example `my_table_f_key` instead of `Table1_id`.

*I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3.*

---

***Edit:-***

In my `project.rb` model:

```
belongs_to :own, :class_name => User
```

In my `user.rb` model:

```
has_many :owned_projects, :class_name => Project, :foreign_key => :owner
```

how I created my project model

```
rails generate scaffold Project name:string owner:integer
```

Now when I access user_id from Project like
`project.owner.userid` it throws exception.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do that? Rails uses that naming convention to enable ActiveRecord to build associations without you explicitly configuring table and foreign key names. Using a different convention is a **bad** idea and only causes problems.

Comment: What naming convention would be used here then?

Comment: @Dan,@Jordan: I want to give two foreign key in one table. Both points to same table. So I want to give two diff name for two foreign keys.

Comment: Are you creating several belongs_to relationships that use the same class?

Comment: well, for a start you need to have `belongs_to :owner` in `project.rb`, and the foreign key in your projects table HAS to be `owner_id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your responses in the comments, this is one way of implementing what you want to do:

Assuming two models in your app (Users and Questions), and two different relationships:

- User asks many Questions, Question belongs_to Asker
- User edits many Questions, Question belongs_to Editor

You could implement this structure in the following way:

```
rails generate scaffold Question asker_id:integer editor_id:integer
```

Specifying `id:integer` in your generate command is redundant, as Rails will generate that column for you automatically. It's also conventional to name your foreign keys in terms of the relationship (ie, `asker_id`).

Then, inside each of your models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asker, :class_name => User
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => User
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :asked_questions, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => :asker_id
  has_many :edited_questions, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => :editor_id
end
```

That way, you can use them together like this:

```
@question.asker # => User
@question.editor # => User

@user.asked_questions # => [Question, Question, Question]
@user.edited_questions # => [Question, Question]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Dan's answer, pass the class name as String.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a class to the `class_name` is deprecated and will raise an ArgumentError in Rails 5.2. It eagerloads more classes than necessary and potentially creates circular dependencies. Please pass the class name as a string

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asker, :class_name => User
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => User
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :asked_questions, :class_name => 'Question', :foreign_key => :asker_id
  has_many :edited_questions, :class_name => 'Question', :foreign_key => :editor_id
end
```