# How to use owner_id (instead of user_id) as foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I'm building an app where a user creates an arbitrary number of groups. When the group is created, the owner_id (in the group table) is set to that of the `current_user.id`.

I'm having some trouble showing the groups owned by a particular user though. Note that there is a many-to-many relationship between users and groups through the GroupMembers table.

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025135/how-to-give-foreign-key-a-name-in-ror-3), I modified my group.rb model like such:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :group_members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :group_members
  belongs_to  :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

Adding just the last line to ("owner") to the model. The problem is that when I display the groups belonging to the user in my view:

```
<h3>User</h3>
<p>User: <%= @user.name %></p>
<p>Email: <%= @user.email if @user.email %></p>
<p>Groups:
  <% @user.groups.each do |group|%>
    <%= group.name %>
   <% end %>
</p>
```

None of the groups show up. It seems that maybe I need to explicitly join to the groups table from inside the UsersController for this to work? But I'm not sure. I don't want to go too far down the rabbit hole here so I'm looking for some advice.

UPDATE:

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :group_members, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :groups, :through => :group_members

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you fetch `@user.groups`, you're using the `:groups` association on the `User` model, which is independent of the `has_one :user` association on the `Group` model. So the code you've provided above isn't the relevant bit. What you need is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

Update: since you've already got a `has_many :groups` relation, you'll need to name this something else. e.g.,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_groups, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: Group
end
```

Then you'll need to update your view code to do `@user.owned_groups` instead of `@user.groups`, or you'll be fetching the wrong collection.

(p.s., the inverse relation on the `Group` model should be `belongs_to :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :owner_id`, not `has_one`. The difference is that a model that `belongs_to` another model is expected to hold the foreign key that defines the relationship, whereas a `has_one` relationship expects the foreign key to be on the associated table.)

Comment: I updated my question. Should I add a second "has_many" line? There is a many-to-many relationship with user and groups (because users act like members). but I want to add a one to many from users to groups as well (because users act like owners, too).

Comment: Awesome. This works. I just needed to changes `@users.groups` to `@users.owned_groups` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
# user.rb
has_many :owned_groups, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: "Group"
```

That will distinguish between groups that the user owns vs groups that the user is in.